# Error in flutter devtools detect leaks tab "TypeError: Instance of 'minified:Kl': type 'minified:Kl' is not a subtype of type 'minified:Hc'"

Tags: android, flutter, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, flutter-devtools

I am using leak_tracker package in flutter to detect memory leaks.
In dev tools in the detect leaks tab when i click on analyse and dowload button
this error is being shown:

`Error: TypeError: Instance of 'minified:Kl': type 'minified:Kl' is not a subtype of type 'minified:Hc`

also this is the output in debug console

```
leak_tracker: 0 memory leak(s): not disposed: 0, not GCed: 0, GCed late: 0
I/flutter (15612): leak_tracker: 18 memory leak(s): not disposed: 18, not GCed: 0, GCed late: 0
I/flutter (15612): leak_tracker: 45 memory leak(s): not disposed: 45, not GCed: 0, GCed late: 0
I/flutter (15612): leak_tracker: 76 memory leak(s): not disposed: 76, not GCed: 0, GCed late: 0
I/flutter (15612): leak_tracker: Error handling leak tracking request from DevTools to application.
I/flutter (15612): leak_tracker: Null check operator used on a null value
I/flutter (15612): leak_tracker: #0      envelopeByType
_protocol.dart:159
I/flutter (15612): #1      sealEnvelope
_protocol.dart:58
I/flutter (15612): #2      ResponseFromApp.toJson
delivery.dart:55
I/flutter (15612): #3      ResponseFromApp.toServiceResponse
delivery.dart:51
I/flutter (15612): #4      setupDevToolsIntegration.handler
_registration.dart:51
I/flutter (15612): #5      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1666:54)
I/flutter (15612): #6      _RootZone.bindBinaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1625:33)
I/flutter (15612): #7      _runExtension (dart:developer-patch/developer.dart:91:23)
```

also can you refer to any resource that has a tutorial on leak detection and handling in flutter,
i have looked it on the internet and everything is quite confusing